# Emphasise font automatically

Tags: fonts, emphasis

I want abbreviations to be written using the `\mathsf` font. For this, I created a command `\mystyle`. I would like these abbreviations to be emphasised in emphasised environments automatically. Is there a way to achieve this?

The naive method presented in the MWE below does not work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\mystyle}[1]{$\mathsf{#1}$}

\begin{document}
    If I write outside of an environment, all is fine, and \mystyle{ABC} is typeset the way it should

    \emph{If I am in an emphasized environment, I want \mystyle{ABC} to be emphasized as well}
\end{document}
```

Comment: why are you using math??? use `\textsf` and it will work as you expect

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh, `\textsf` exists... Whoops!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a text font, not math.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\mystyle}[1]{\textsf{#1}}

\begin{document}
    If I write outside of an environment, all is fine, and \mystyle{ABC} is typeset the way it should

    \emph{If I am in an emphasized environment, I want \mystyle{ABC} to be emphasized as well}
\end{document}
```